# Dynamically create folders and files from table columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am tasked with organising our lab dataset into CSV files so as to share it with other researchers. This is basically a dataset about people's GPS traces spread across multiple tables.

To best describe the task at hand, I give an example. Table `trips` contains data about user trips (such as length of a trip), and table `sessions` stores user's sessions and corresponding GPS traces logged. So that:

```
postgres=# select * from trips;
 trip_id | session_ids | length
---------+-------------+--------
     101 | {100,200}   |  501.2
     102 | {300,400}   |  70.13
     103 | {500}       |  102.3
(3 rows)

postgres=# select * from sessions;
 user_id | session_id | timestamp |  lat  |  lon
---------+------------+-----------+-------+-------
       1 |        100 |       120 |  8.12 | 50.22
       1 |        100 |       122 |  8.33 | 50.31
       1 |        200 |       146 | 11.01 | 50.25
       1 |        200 |       147 | 11.86 | 49.38
       2 |        300 |       250 |  8.51 | 39.21
       2 |        300 |       251 |  8.34 | 39.38
       2 |        400 |       115 |  8.05 | 40.01
       2 |        400 |       116 |  8.17 | 39.02
       2 |        500 |       300 |  8.76 | 40.22
       2 |        500 |       302 |  8.13 | 40.23
(10 rows)
```

The two tables are joined `ON session_id = ANY(session_ids)`.

**How to organise data on files:**

We want to organise the data in a way that for each user, we create a folder corresponding to the `user_id`,  then inside each user folder, we store user's GPS trace with file name corresponding to that user's `trip_id`. Doing this recursively since there are over 300 users, with several hundred trips per user.

Considering the given example, the required directory structure is:

```
Data
├── 1
│   ├── 101.csv
├── 2
│   ├── 102.csv
│   ├── 103.csv  
├──
```

So that `101.csv` contains the GPS traces for all sessions covered by user `1` in trip `101` like so:

```
session_id,timestamp,lat,lon
100,120,8.12,50.22
100,122,8.33,50.31
200,146,11.01,50.25
200,147,11.86,49.38
```

and `102.csv` should be:

```
session_id,timestamp,lat,lon
300,250,8.51,39.21
300,251,8.34,39.38
400,115,8.05,40.01
400,116,8.17,39.02
```

Similarly file `103.csv`. Currently, I can only display the content of the table using:

```
import psycopg2
from config import config

conn = None
try:
    #read connection parameters
    params = config()
    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    # declare a cursor object from the connection
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sessions')

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

And then:

```
$ python3 get_data.py 
Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...
[(1, 100, 120, 8.12, 50.22), (1, 100, 122, 8.33, 50.31), (1, 200, 144, 8.51,
 39.21), (1, 200, 146, 8.12, 39.21), (2, 300, 250, 11.01, 49.38), (2, 300, 251, 
11.01,39.21), (2, 400, 115, 8.12, 50.12), (2, 400, 116, 8.11, 50.11), (2, 500, 300, 
8.76, 40.22), (2, 500, 302, 8.13, 40.23)]
```

What should I do to be able to organise the data on files as state above:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but it should work.

```
import psycopg2
from config import config

conn = None

#read connection parameters
params = config()
# connect to the PostgreSQL server
print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

# declare a cursor object from the connection
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER BY user_id, session_id')

last_user = ''
last_sess = ''
fcsv = None
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    user = str(row[0])
    if user != last_user:
        last_user = user
        if not os.path.isdir(user):
            os.mkdir(f"Data/{user}")
        last_sess = ''
    sess = str(row[1])
    if sess != last_sess:
        if fcsv:
            fcsv.close()
        fcsv = open( f"Data/{user}/{sess}.csv", 'w' )
        print('session_id,timestamp,lat,lon', file=fcsv)
        last_sess = sess
    print( f"{sess},{row[2]},{row[3]},{row[4]}", file=fcsv )
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim, this is an extremely wonderful solution. With little modification, I achieve the goal.

Comment: So one can use `print` to write to a file..? Genious!

Comment: One quick question, please. Suppose the result set is such a large number of rows, (say 9M rows) how does replacing `fetchall()` with `fetchmany()` fit here? since the latter need be called repeatedly to get the next rows.

Comment: You'd just set up a nested loop.   `while True:` / `rowset = cursor.fetchmany()` / `if not rowset:` / `break` / `for row in rowset:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `itertools.groupby`-function to window your result on python level and the `csv` module for serializing. More on groupby [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Note that your data input has to be pre-sorted by user_id and trip_id.

```
import csv
import pathlib
import itertools

[your code]

data_dir = pathlib.Path("Data")
pathlib.Path("Data").mkdir(exist_ok=True)  # Creating folder if it doesn't exist
for (user, trip), rows in itertools.groupby(data, lambda row: (row[0], row[1])):
    user_dir = data_dir / str(user)
    user_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    file = user_dir / "{}.csv".format(trip)
    with open(file, "w", newline="") as writefile:
        writer = csv.writer(writefile)
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row[2:])  # ignore the grouping columns
```

Comment: That's clever, but they have to be grouped by both user id and session id.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, forgot that while writing :D I edited it, it should work for you now